# Retrieving each selected row values using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I am using following jquery code to read checkbox selected rows using each class. One row html is

```
<input id="_GridView3_chkEmployee" type="checkbox" name="$GridView3$ctl02$chkEmployee" />
        </td><td>
                    <span id="GridView3_ctl02_lblId" class="IDName">687</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="_GridView3_ctl02_lblCompany" class="FName">Xyz Inc.</span>
                </td><td>
                    <span id="_GridView3_ctl02_lblDun">12323</span>
                </td>
```

Problem with following jquery code is that alert will show all the values for IDName and FName instead of just showing the checked row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#submit").click(function () {
       alert("starting");
       $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
           alert($('.IDName').text());
           alert($('.FName').text());
       });
   });
});
```

How can I get this code to just alert for single .IDName and .FName values for the selected row that is checked? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this -

```
$("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
          alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.IDName').text());
          alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.FName').text());
});
```